# How to inherit a width of webgrid's columns to header names after setting the position: fixed at header style?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

my question is how to inherit a width of webgrid's columns to header names after setting the position: fixed at header style?
I searched a lot but nothing helped and I still cant understand how to do it.

If the position is not fixed then all is well:
[all right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpifE.png)

But i need a fixed header of my table. In this case:
[all bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhcEI.png)

My code:

Index.cshtml:

```
<div id="mainGrid" style="padding-top: 100px;">
    @Html.Partial("../Home/Grid", Model)
</div>
```

Grid.cshtml:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(
        source: Model,
        canPage: false,
        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "mainGrid"
    );
}
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(header: "", columnName: "isChecked", canSort: false, style: "checkbox",
            format: @<text><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value=@item.id /></text>),
        grid.Column(header: "Name", columnName: "name", style: "name"),
        grid.Column(header: "Type", columnName: "type", style: "type"),
        grid.Column(header: "Date", columnName: "date", style: "date"),
        grid.Column(header: "Size", columnName: "size", style: "size")
    ),
    tableStyle: "grid_table",
    headerStyle: "header_table",
    rowStyle: "row_table",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt-row_table"
)
```

Grid.css (important part):

```
.grid_table { 
    background-color: white;
    width: 1000px; 
    height: 500px;
    text-align: left;  
    display: inline-block;
    border-collapse: separate; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: auto;      
}

.grid_table th, tr {        
    height: 50px;
}

.header_table {
    color: black;
    background-color: limegreen;  
    width: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;  
    position: fixed; 
    margin-top: -50px; 
}
```

Please help me to understand and solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is not solved. I chose a different path - I removed the webgrid's header, then I implemented it myself (just a single "table" with Ajax.ActionLink elements). Actually looks not bad, especially considering the necessity of my sorting.